# Cual regla de eslint aplico para imponer solo un salto de linea después de cada sentencia?

Tags: javascript, eslint

mi problema es que quiero configurar eslint para que detecte error cuando detecte mas de un salto de linea después de cada sentencia de código.

```
 console.log('1');



 console.log(' 2');
```

Estas son las reglas que tengo activas actualmente:

```
"rules": {
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "windows"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "double"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "never"
    ]
}
```

Pensaba que linebreack-style me ayudaría para esto pero no parece funcionar. Estoy utilizando la v5.16 de eslint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no me equivoco [es la siguiente](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines):

```
"no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { "max": 1, "maxEOF": 1,"maxBOF": 1 }]
```

Los campos de configuración son los siguientes:

- max: Máximo número de líneas en blanco (por defecto 2).
- maxEOF: Máximo número de líneas en blanco al final del fichero (End Of File).
- maxBOF: Máximo número de líneas en blanco al inicio del fichero (Beginning Of File).

Comment: funciona bien. gracias